# Interfacing PCA9955 I2C LED driver

Tags: avr, i2c

I want to interface ATmega128 to PCA9955 LED driver using TWi communication mode. The TWI is ok but even so the PCA9955 doesn't acknowledge it. I am trying to light up LED 14 without using PWM. My code is here. I have connected AD0, AD1 and AD2 pins of PCA9955 to ground so address is device address is 0x02. Can anyone tell me what did I miss here regarding PCA9955 LED driver ?

```
void master_twi_init(void)
{
    TWSR = 0x03;
    TWBR = 124; // SCl frequency 1000Hz (approximately) 
}

void device_init(void)
{
    stdout = &uart0_str;
    uart0_init();
    master_twi_init();
}

int main(void){
    device_init();
    _delay_ms(5);
    twi_tx_byte(0x05, 0b00010000); // Set LED 14 fully bright
    while(1){;}
}

void twi_tx_byte(uint8_t addr, uint8_t data)
{
    TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWSTA)|(0<<TWSTO)|(1<<TWEN);

    while (!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)));
    if ((TWSR & 0xF8) != 0x08){printf("Start error.\r\n");}     
    _delay_ms(100);

    TWDR = 0xC0;      //For now all addresses are connected to ground
    TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEN);
    while(!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)));
    if ((TWSR & 0xF8) != 0x18){printf("device ack err.\r\n");}
    _delay_ms(100);

    TWDR = addr;
    TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEN);    
    while(!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)));
    if ((TWSR & 0xF8) != 0x28){printf("address ack err.\r\n");}
    _delay_ms(100);

    TWDR = data;
    TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEN);
    while(!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)));
    if ((TWSR & 0xF8) != 0x28){printf("data ack err.\r\n");}
    _delay_ms(100);

    TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWSTO);
}
```

The output I get is.

```
device ack err.
address ack err.
data ack err.
```

The only thing that is okay is 'Start' of I2C.

This is my circuit.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to this [datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PCA9952_PCA9955.pdf), the 9955 has 4 address pins. You need to pull A3 low or high, too.

But even then, the address is not `0x02`. In Fig.3 in section 7.1.1, the address is shown to be

```
1 1 0 A3 A2 A1 A0 R/W
```

So if you ground all the pins, the device address should be 0xC0 or 0xC1, depending on whether you are reading or writing to it.

Comment: I made changes as you told. I was looking at datasheet of PCA9955A so it was different. The datasheet you provided me was of 9955 but still I can't communicate with it with address pins A3, A2, A1, A0 connected to ground or VDD.

Comment: It would be helpful if you updated the code in your question to show the new address. Also, indicate exactly what the output from the console you are getting.

Comment: I have posted the edited code with output and also circuit diagram above. I think that there is problem with hardware but I don't know where it is..

Comment: I also checked at other possible adresses by connecting address pins to 5v through 10k resistor (pull-up resistor)as suggested in datasheet . the voltage at those address pins were 0.9~1v. I don't know what this is supposed to mean...